# Is there a way to configure OneLogin apps from the catalog using their API?

Tags: configuration, deterministic, onelogin

I'd like to ensure that my OneLogin configuration state is versioned and recreatable. As such, programmatic capability of configuring apps would be invaluable. Searching through their API docs, I did not find any way to do this. Using the webview means that I don't have these changes in configuration tracked and versioned and I also can't configure them through an automated workflow which would let me recover a deterministic app / directory state quickly.

Any help with a solution to this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

At this time you can't do that via API.